# Enquiy submission layout creation

Tags: android

I want to create an enquiry submission form for a product as in the image. Whenever I run the code the components are not in its proper place.

[image]

Help me to design. The `editText` field will go to the edge of screen and button will also go somewhere else than the desired location when app running...
How to make this layout work on every device. I am a newbie to android.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:background="@drawable/bg"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
                android:text="PRODUCT NAME"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView17"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/itemImages"
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/offer"
                android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp" />



            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/offer"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="190dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/itemImages"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/itemImages"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
                android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/reviewInput"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/itemImages"
                android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/submitReview"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/submitReview"
                android:background="@drawable/boarder"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/Write_an_enquiry"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:padding="5dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/submitReview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/itemImages"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/itemImages"
                android:layout_below="@+id/reviewInput"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:background="@color/accent"
                android:onClick="insertReview"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="@string/submit"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="ENQUIRY SUBMISSION"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Submit button not properly showing right?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed bro edittext not showing

Comment: Is keyboard overlapping the `editText`?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed no bro

Comment: @FaysalAhmed it is on right side edge

Comment: I just execute you design and the edittext showing properly at the bottom with full wide. When keyboard open then keyboard overlapping the edittext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:text="PRODUCT NAME"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Large" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="43dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="43dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

     <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemImages"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/offer"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="13dp" />



    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/offer"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/itemImages"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/itemImages"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/reviewInput"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/submitReview"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:background="@drawable/boarder"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Write_an_enquiry"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitReview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:onClick="insertReview"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="submit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView19"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="ENQUIRY SUBMISSION"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml` add this line to your activity.

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Hope this will fix the problem.